# Powershell script duplicating files and displaying incorrect URL of the file's location

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, url, duplicate, csv

I have a powershell script that display a list of files that are checked out all users in a site and exports the output as a csv file:

```
 Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
$url = "contoso.com"
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url)
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
$list = $web.Lists

function Get-DocInventory() {   

                $web = Get-SPWeb "http://portal.contoso.com"

                    foreach ($list in $web.Lists) {

                        if ($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary") {

                         $dList = [Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPDocumentLibrary]$list
                         $items = $dList.Items
                         $files = $dList.CheckedOutFiles

                        foreach($file in $files){

                           foreach($item in $items){

                                if($item["Checked Out To"] -ne $null){

                             $wuse = $file.DirName.Substring($web.ServerRelativeUrl.Length)                          
                             $modifiedTime = $web.RegionalSettings.TimeZone
                             $data = @{
                                "Version" = $item["Version"]
                                "library" = $wuse
                                "URL" = $web.Url + ('/') + $item.Url
                                "Title" = $file.LeafName
                                "CheckedOut By" = $file.CheckedOutBy.Name
                                "Time last Modified" = $modifiedTime.UTCToLocalTime($file.TimeLastModified)

                            }
                           }

                              New-Object PSObject -Property $data

                            }
                          }                        
                       }
                    }
                    $web.Dispose();
                }
                $site.Dispose()

        }

Get-DocInventory | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path D:\Docinventory.csv
```

I have an example of what the script outputs as shown below:
[image]

My question is, can someone please help/tell me why for the example shown above, it duplicates the file (Orangutans.docx) multiple times? In addition, the output displays the incorrect URL. The putout should only display one URL and it should be http://contoso.com/sites/Depts3/KDS/RP1MajorVersions/Orangutans.docx.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the checked-out files, then I believe you should not loop over the list items in your code i.e. remove `foreach($item in $items)` which is present inside `foreach($file in $files)`. Moreover, if you want to get the `SPListItem` associated with the `SPFile`, you can use `SPListItem.File` property for that.

Comment: So in essence, you're advising me to replace the line foreach($item in $items) with SPListItem.File? Please advise.

Comment: That should be the first step. But I haven't tested your script.